# How can I check if a configuration parameter exists?

Tags: php, symfony, configuration, undefined

I use Symfony 2.3.x for an application I currently develop.

I have this structure in my `app/config/` folder:

- `environment/dev/file.yml`
- `environment/test/file.yml`
- `environment/myenv/file.yml`
- and so on

In each of these files, I have something like:

```
parameters:
    myvalue: 2000
```

In my `Controller`, I do this:

```
$v = $this->container->getParameter('myvalue');
var_dump($v);
```

The above code will dump the value `int 2000`.

So everything works great.

---

But I want to handle the situation where `myvalue` is not defined. If I simply delete this variable from the YAML files, I get an HTTP 500 error with a huge stack-trace.

I want to do something like:

```
if (variable_exists ('myvalue')) {
    $x = $this->container->getParameter('myvalue');
else {
    $x = SOME_DEFAULT_VALUE;
}

useVariable($x);
```

Does Symfony have some sort of function that does what the `variable_exists()` function mentioned above does ?

I couldn't find anything in the docs.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: have you tried with `if($this->container->hasParameter("myvalue")) ...`?

Comment: @ponciste Nope, didn't try that one, I thought it was only for services. It works, though, thanks.

Comment: could i post it as answer and you mark mine as correct please? @Radu Murzea

Comment: @ponciste You could. But won't changing the accepted answer be a little rude considering they're identical ?

Comment: well, it doesn't matter. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try calling `$container->hasParameter('myvalue');`. See [here](http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/components/dependency_injection/parameters.html) for more details.

Comment: I don't know why you got downvoted, as it turns it out this is the correct answer.

Comment: pfff. When I answered there isn't any comment. @RaduMurzea give the vote to ponciste. I don't care about the votes but only to give contribute when is possibile ( open source philosophy VS self-love philosophy ).

Comment: Neah, it's fine, you deserve it :) .